# ASP.NET accessing value of the textboxes inside of the repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, textbox, repeater

I want to check values of textboxes inside of a repeater. If all textboxes are empty i want to assign the check value to 0. I tried this implementation but i got this error `System.InvalidCastException`

```
            int check = 0;

            foreach (TextBox tb in searchResultRepeater.Items)
            {
             if(tb.Text == ""){
                check = 0;
             }else{
                check = 1;
             }
            }
```

How can i fix this exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that not all object in Items collection are instances of TextBox.
You need to run your loop with a tb defined as a more generic object and then check inside of the loop if tb is a TextBox

```
 foreach(RepeaterItem item in searchResultRepeater.Items){
    for (int i = 0; i < item.Controls.Count; i++) {
        Control ctrl = item.Controls[i];    
        if(ctrl is TextBox){
           TextBox tb = (TextBox) ctrl;
           if (tb.Text != null && tb.Text.Length > 0) {
                        check = 1;
                        break;
           }
        }
   }
   if (check == 1)
       break;
 }
```

Comment: inside of the if statement - tb.Text.Length

Comment: Updated one more time. If it doesn't work, I'm giving up, because I don't have VisualStudio installed  to test, but you should have an idea now and can test it yourself.

Comment: Why do we need two nested loops for the solution ?

Comment: because there might be more than one child control in a RepeaterItem according to the documentation

Answer (score 1):

If your searchResultRepeter is an Repeater instead of looping though TextBoxes you should be using RepeaterItem. You can check if all of your items are acctualy the TextBox type.

```
    foreach(RepeaterItem item in searchResultRepeater.Items){
        if(item.Controls.Count > 0 && item.Controls[0] is ITextControl ) {
           if(((TextBox)item.Controls[0]).Text.IsNullOrEmpty()){
                check = 1;
                break;
       }
    }
```

Comment: what kind of error did you get? was it the InvaildCastException again?

Comment: Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox. This the error.

Comment: I have forgotten that to access WebControl on RepeaterItem we have to use Controls property. You can change your if statement (I've changed the code snippet above).

Comment: i'am sorry but error again in the second if statement

Comment: 'No overload for method 'IsNullOrEmpty' takes 0 arguments'